# Draw a 3d rectangular box(rectangular prism ?) in wpf

Tags: wpf

I am using the following code to form a cube. It uses triangles for each face. How can I make a rectangular box by modifying its values. I dont have much idea on the indices property used here.

```
 <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
 <MeshGeometry3D
 Positions = "-1,-1,1 1,-1,1 1,1,1 -1,1,1"
 TriangleIndices = "0 1 2     2,3,0"
 TextureCoordinates="0,1 1,1 1,0 0,0"
 />
 </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
```

Comment: prism, rectangular box? do you mean a cube?

Answer (score 1):

here you go

```
<GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
    <MeshGeometry3D Positions = "0 0 0  1 0 0  0 1 0  1 1 0  0 0 1  1 0 1  0 1 1  1 1 1"
                    TriangleIndices = "2 3 1  2 1 0  7 1 3  7 5 1  6 5 7  6 4 5  6 2 0  2 0 4  2 7 3  2 6 7  0 1 5  0 5 4"/>
</GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
```

this will produce a cube geometry

I would suggest you to understand how it work so you can make other objects too

here is a nice tutorial on WPF 3D

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24727/WPF-D-Part-of-n